# Angular 6 - Unable to convert DatePipe

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to set a current date in my formGroup with specific format, i tried with the below code, but i get this error

> 'Unable to convert "13/07/2020" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'

```
this.fb.group({
      startdateActivity: [this.datePipe.transform(new Date().toLocaleString().substring(0, 10), "yyyy-dd-MM"), Validators.required]
})

<input type="date" formControlName="startdateActivity"/>
```

Comment: You will also need to bind to this date in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code below.

If **startdateActivity** type is **string**

```
   let date = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), "yyyy-dd-MM");
    this.fb.group({
          startdateActivity: [date.toString(), Validators.required]
    });
```

If **startdateActivity** type is **date**

```
 let date = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), "yyyy-dd-MM");
    this.fb.group({
          startdateActivity: [date, Validators.required]
    })
```

Comment: The error doesn't show anymore, but the value, but the value is not set in an input of type date

Comment: Console.log the date

Comment: If my answer works for you, please accept the answer.